# Are there mathematical proof info-graphics?

Tags: proofs, logic, discrete-math, visual-proof

I am teaching mathematical proof to kids (10th grade) and am of the opinion that proofs of theorems are a good place to start, where almost all of mathematics' important players come together.

On one side, we have logical structures like propositions, consequence, rules of inferences, propositional logic/calculus, etc.

Then we have formal system, axiomatic system of natural numbers say, on the other side, which has structures of math like axioms, primitive notions/functions, theorems, lemmas etc.

And then we have proof itself where there are various techniques like direct proof/ indirect proof, reasoning (deductive reasoning), using various axioms, theorems etc.

Kids usually struggle with every one of these concepts, let alone all of them together. It is difficult to get the whole picture and all the moving parts. So this place (proof) seems like a good place to show all of this in action. I could make [infographics](https://venngage.com/blog/what-is-an-infographic/) myself, but it would take some time. So I wanted to know whether someone *already* has done such and is willing to share?

Also, if I were to create such an infographic, how do you suggest I begin, and what, in your opinion, *must* it include?

**[Edit]**: I uploaded an initial version of infographic to github, please click [here](https://github.com/shukash/Mathematical-Proof-Infographic/blob/master/Mathematical%20Proofs.pdf) to see. I VERY EAGERLY wait for your INVALUABLE feedback/suggestions to improve this infographic...

Comment: It seems to me that most of the listed ideas are best illustrated, the more so for novices, by specific, well chosen examples, rather than as parts of some grand scheme that will almost necessarily be completely opaque to someone without experience. Start with some simple statements that illustrate something simple, such as that although A imply B, B need not imply A.

Comment: Can you post the age of the kids, rather than a reference to an unspecified country's education system? I have no idea how old a 10th grader is.

Comment: 10th graders in the U.S. are usually about 15 years old.

Comment: I guess that's about the age for 10th grader all around the world. I am surprised there are people who don't know the age of 10th graders...

Comment: @AshishShukla: Different countries start primary education at different ages. Also, not all countries use the terminology "grade".

Comment: In Singapore for example, the equivalent of 10th graders are what we call "secondary 4" students, who are usually $16$. So unless you want to restrict your question to the US, you really should be aware of conventions elsewhere in the world.

Comment: @Namaste I actually don't think so. Before I taught kids I really thought that Abstraction, Complexity would be too much for kids to understand. But BOY WAS I WRONG. Kids have amazing capacity to learn and put an effort, PROVIDED things are explained properly. So No I don't think kids would be overwhelmed. I don't want to go to the level of details of logic I just want to give an Idea of moving parts in ALL proofs, like proof contains has approach Direct/Indirect, then how is Logic involved in it and how is structure of math like Axioms, theorems involved with a Proof?

Comment: With regard to the recent edit, this looks like a new question.  Rather than editing the existing question in order to ask for feedback, it would be better to create a new question.

Comment: @AshishShukla These are great! I will take a look at the content in a bit but format wise I would say you're already going big, so I would double the size of each poster and make the boxes a little more comfortable. But this is a great collection of information!

Comment: @NateBade Thanks. I always was confused with the "things" in proof so just wanted to put all of those at one place. Poster size is already A3 so Increasing the size further may not be that good for printing that's why I kept it at that and didn't increase. When viewed on a big screen like I project it on my TV and it looks pretty cool in it...

Answer (score 4):

**Math With Bad Drawing** has some images that approach an info-graph (and in general is just  a great website for math education), for example:

https://mathwithbaddrawings.com/2015/07/01/infinity-plus-one-please-check-your-intuitions-at-the-front-desk/

There are some good geometry ones, especially around old compass and straight-edge constructions but that wont really give you rules of inference. For instance

http://www.noborubitoy.com/?p=119

Finally, you could look into **flowchart proofs**, but I haven't found many graphically nice examples. Here is an example:

https://www.maa.org/programs/faculty-and-departments/curriculum-department-guidelines-recommendations/teaching-and-learning/flowcharting-proofs

I'll be following this question, I've been looking for some decent proof visualizations as well.

Comment: Thanks for the links but I am not looking for proof of any particular theorem. I am looking to put all the moving part of the "Proof" itself in an infographic, like what Proof contains Proof Technique(Direct/Indirect), Reasoning vs Logic, various Inference rules etc. such that kids gets to see All the ingredients of a Proof.

Comment: I uploaded the infographic in github. Please have a look, link in Question's edited section. Your feedback and suggestions are highly appreciated...

Answer (score 3):

> "Kids usually struggle with every one of these concepts, let alone all of them together. It is difficult to get the whole picture and all the moving parts. So this place (proof) seems like a good place to show all of this in action."

I'm afraid there is no "complete picture" of all the facets of logic and proof that you mention, interrelating in one infograph.

Here are some examples of infographs for some components you'd like to include in a combined infograph:

[Laws of logic](https://infograph.venngage.com/p/196211/laws-of-logic)

[Math and Logic Thinking](https://infograph.venngage.com/p/102614/math-and-logic-thinking)

[Logical fallacies](https://www.informationisbeautiful.net/visualizations/rhetological-fallacies/)

[logic diagram flowcharts](https://www.google.com/search?q=logic+diagram+flowcharts&tbm=isch&source=univ&client=firefox-b-1-d&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjyg6T3w_nkAhUxh-AKHeyJCNAQ7Al6BAgCECQ&biw=1366&bih=642)

If you decide to work on this project yourself, [here are some tools for creating infographs](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&q=tools+for+infographics).

Comment: Information is beautiful is a great source for infographics.

Comment: Thanks for the links but I am not looking for proof of any particular theorem. I am looking to put all the moving part of the "Proof" itself in an infographic, like what Proof contains Proof Technique(Direct/Indirect), Reasoning vs Logic, various Inference rules etc. such that kids gets to see All the ingredients of a Proof.

Comment: Please see these cautionary sites which speak exactly to my point in my previous comment:  [7 Mistakes to Avoid When You Create an Infograph](https://venngage.com/blog/create-an-infographic/); [infographic warning signs](https://neilpatel.com/blog/infographic-warning-signs/)

Comment: [Infographic Tools for Educators](https://www.ebsco.com/blog/article/infographics-tools-for-enhancing-instruction-and-assessment)

Comment: @Namaste I uploaded an initial version of Infographic on github. I have provided link in the "Edit" section of the question. I request you to have a look and provide your invaluable feedback and suggestions...